# makefile:15: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile, separator

I know that there have been questions about "Missing separator. Stop." on SE before, but I can't figure out where my makefile is going wrong.

While my program installation is running, this comes up in the terminal:

```
*     Executing: 'make all -f makefile install INSTALL_DIR=/home/leomr/mcell_workspace/mcell_tools/work/build_cellblender' ['make', 'all', '-f', 'makefile', 'install', 'INSTALL_DIR=/home/leomr/mcell_workspace/mcell_tools/work/build_cellblender'] in '/home/leomr/mcell_workspace/cellblender'
makefile:15: *** missing separator.  Stop.
* Exit code: 2
* Error: Error: command 'make all -f makefile install INSTALL_DIR=/home/leomr/mcell_workspace/mcell_tools/work/build_cellblender' failed, terminating.
```

When I "vi makefile" within my cellblender directory, I get this:

```
UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)
#ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
#       INSTALL_DIR = ~/.config/blender/2.78/scripts/addons/
##      INSTALL_DIR = ~/src/blender/Blender-2.78c-CellBlender-linux/2.78/scripts/addons/
#else
#       INSTALL_DIR = /Applications/Blender-2.78c-CellBlender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.78/scripts/addons/
#endif

# CellBlender will be installed here. This should typically be a link to the desired location on your platform.
# For example, on a Linux machine it might be done with: ln -s ~/.config/blender/2.78/scripts/addons/ ~/my_cellblender_link
# For example, on a MacOSX machine it might be done with: ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Blender/2.78/scripts/addons/ ~/my_cellblender_link
# For example, for a link pointing into a Linux bundle: ln -s ~/src/blender/Blender-2.78c-CellBlender-linux/2.78/scripts/addons/ ~/my_cellblender_link
# For example, for a link pointing into a MacOSX bundle: ln -s /Applications/Blender-2.78c-CellBlender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.78/scripts/addons/ ~/my_cellblender_link

<<<<<<< HEAD
INSTALL_DIR ?= ~/my_cellblender_link/
=======
INSTALL_DIR = ~/my_cellblender_link/
>>>>>>> refs/remotes/origin/master

# Linux:
<<<<<<< HEAD
#INSTALL_DIR = ~/.config/blender/2.78/scripts/addons/
=======
#INSTALL_DIR = ~/.config/blender/2.76/scripts/addons/
>>>>>>> refs/remotes/origin/master
.
.
. (this continues for a while)
```

The 15th line is the first "<<<<<<< HEAD".

What's going on here? Should there be a tab anywhere where there isn't?

I'm using Debian 10, via virtualbox. I've been told the program I'm installing works with Debian 10, though it was written for Debian 9.

Comment: That's a merge conflict marker -- you've done a git merge (or whatever SCC tool you're using) and had a conflict and not resolved it.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I don't want to change the makefile, so perhaps I'm pulling the wrong branch. If I were using the same repo as written in line 19 (>>>>>>> refs/remotes/origin/master), which I'm not, then I imagine I wouldn't get this. Correct?

Comment: The problem is that you're not on any (valid) branch -- you've (tried to have) done a merge between branches and is has failed.  Or someone else did and checked it into the repo (meaning they corrupted the branch).

Comment: Q: What version control *are* you using?  Git?  the "diffs" (aka "conflict markers") you see *SHOULDN'T* actually be checked in.  So in theory, *any* "clean checkout" should give you an "uncorrupted"version.  See my notes below.

Answer (score 0):

If you see stuff like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
INSTALL_DIR ?= ~/my_cellblender_link/
=======
INSTALL_DIR = ~/my_cellblender_link/
>>>>>>> refs/remotes/origin/master
```

You're looking at a "diff" - very possibly a [patch file](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/development/creating-patches.html).

In simpler terms, the file is "corrupt".

You need to fix it.

Specifically:

1. Decide *which* "INSTALL_DIR" is correct, and DELETE the other 4 lines.
2. Rinse and repeat for every `<<<<<<< HEAD` `>>>>>>>` pair you find.

---

What I said above is correct:

- That funny `<<<<<<< HEAD` `>>>>>>>` text you're seeing is a "diff" between one version of the makefile and another.  That's often how "patches" are made; it can also be your version control system noting a "conflict" between one source version and another.
- The bottom line is this particular makefile is "corrupt".  You need to fix it.
- One alternative is to edit it manually, as I suggested above.

It didn't occur to me earlier, but maybe what's happening is that you had an "old" version of your project, you did a checkout of a "newer" version on top of it ... and your version control tool introduced the corruption.

ANOTHER SUGGESTION:

- Check out the entire project into a new, *CLEAN* directory.

Please let us know what happens!

Comment: That is absolutely not a diff, nor is it a patch file.  As mentioned in the comments above, this is the result of a 3-way merge from a source control tool (Git, Mercurial, Subversion, etc.)  Diffs and patch files are different than that.

Comment: Fine.  If you're guess is correct, the best suggestion is *still* a clean checkout to a fresh directory.  Checking out the latest version (which is probably OK) or, worse case, an earlier version (before the conflict was introduced upstream).

Comment: Agreed, that is the way to go.